# connected combo boxes in continuous form - the second combo doesn't show its value if dependent on first combo how could I fix that

Tags: ms-access

I have a Continuous Form that has two combo boxes. If I don't link them together all values appear but if I link the two combo boxes to make one of them depend on other for easier choose from, the values never show in the second combo. I try to make code with if condition in vba to requery the combo values to show in all records but I couldn't. How could I do that?  Thank you for all what you do

Comment: Welcome to SO. To give your question better quality/clarity you could add some images which will help others answer correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique is known as cascading combobox. A very common topic. Be aware that if combobox RowSource uses an alias (displays text when saving ID) the text will not be available for display in all records when the list is filtered. This is especially disconcerting for users of continuous/datasheet view form.

Could have code that only filters second combobox when it gets focus then restore the full list when loses focus. Users will still see data briefly disappear from other records and may find distracting at first but will learn to disregard.

However, a workaround to maintain display of text is to include the combobox  RowSource lookup table in a query used as form RecordSource. Bind a textbox to the descriptive text field from lookup table. Set textbox as Locked Yes and TabStop No. In continuous view, can size and position textbox on top of combobox to obscure combobox text but still show drop arrow (a "hybrid" control). In datasheet view the textbox will not be superimposed but text will be displayed.

If controls are superimposed, users accustomed to clicking into combobox text frame and typing input will encounter aggravation as the textbox will likely be the control they click. Tabbing to the combobox or clicking drop arrow will cause combobox to get focus and display over the textbox.

Comment: I try it the hybrid controls it magnificent idea but  it work some times and when try to add additional record it turned to codes symbols #ED and need to refresh all form every refreash some times text appear normlly and some times not all record appear is there any solve for these issues

Comment: can you more explain what i will do with the textbox that will show above the second combobox I chose the tabstop and locked it and i didnt understand am I need to connect it with the second combobox such as control source=secondcombobox.text

Comment: As instructed, textbox is simply bound to field. Did you build query to use as form RecordSource? You should edit your question with info about attempt (code and sample data). And no, it makes no sense to have expression referencing combobox.

Comment: I add to the source query the column of the second value of  second combo box and back to the continuous form and make the above textbox control source refer to its column on the query  it work perfectly i spend 3 days cant sleep because of this and it solved here in 2 Min thanks a lot and for all how help there in this site

Comment: Glad for that. If answer resolves issue please mark it accepted.

Comment: I mark It sorry for the delay