# How to create dynamic cascading combo boxes in ms access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, cascadingdropdown, subform, continuous-forms

So the problem is that i am having two combo boxes in ms access subform. First is ProductID and Second is BatchID. I want to filter the BatchID for the ProductID I select.

I have placed the following code to filter the BatchID

```
Private Sub SetReSrc()
    Me.cbo_BatchID.RowSource = "qry_BatchID"
End Sub

Private Sub cbo_ProductID_AfterUpdate()
    SetReSrc
End Sub
```

For the first record it works fine. But as I enter the Product in the next record it removes the previous BatchIDs. It makes sense that it is updating the BatchID to the current selected ProductID but i want to keep the earlier ones and update only the last one.

How can I can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Answer (score 0):

"For the first record it works fine. But as I enter the Product in the next record it removes the previous BatchIDs. It makes sense that it is updating the BatchID to the current selected ProductID but i want to keep the earlier ones and update only the last one."

If the batchids is a tied to a field as the control source, then MS Access is already doing what you want, by keeping/storing all previous values of the batchid to each record.

Ensure you are not using an unbound form control  for the batchid.

Comment: Yeah the control is bound and it is adding/storing the records. but as i type or select from the itemid in the next record it kinda hides previous ones from the form. but behind the scene the data is being stored in the table.

Comment: Try adding the code to the form's on current event.

Comment: yeah i did, same result.