# Filtering form results based on active not displaying data

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have a combo box filtering results in a subform based on the region the suppliers are located and also uses a checkbox to filter combo options based on active and inactive.

```
Like IIf([Forms]![rfrmSupplierRegion]![IsActive],True,"*")
```

This is in the criteria for the combo box record source query and is working fine. I then put it into the subform record source query in the criteria for the SupplierID. When I untick to show inactive it will show all results but when ticking the box with both queries having the criteria it shows only the regions in the combo box that have active records but the form shows no data.

I want the form to only show active records when it is ticked and show all when not.

[Main form with subform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD6XI.png)

Main form Record Source

```
SELECT tblAddress.*, tblSuppliers.IsActive FROM tblSuppliers INNER JOIN tblAddress ON tblSuppliers.ID = tblAddress.SupplierID;
```

SQL of the unbound combo box

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblLocation.Region
FROM tblSuppliers INNER JOIN (tblLocation INNER JOIN tblAddress ON tblLocation.ID = tblAddress.LocationID) ON tblSuppliers.ID = tblAddress.SupplierID
WHERE (((tblSuppliers.IsActive) Like IIf([Forms]![rfrmSupplierRegion]![IsActive],True,"*")))
ORDER BY tblLocation.Region;
```

Comment: Not clear to me what the issue is. Title says inactive records still displayed but narrative says form shows no data. See if answer to this question explains your situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Comment: Adjusted title. Before I added the criteria to the subform it was still displaying all results regardless of checkbox being ticked or not. The above link didn't really assist.

Comment: Edit question to show the complete form RecordSource SQL. Sample data as text table(s) might be helpful as well. Is main form just an unbound form?

Comment: common task with many examples.  Call this filter form with unbound combobox and unbound checkbox.  The combobox and checkbox will have the same afterUpdate event. where you set the form's filter and requery the form.  Here is a link to one of many youtube videos on variants of the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax-sC2wCPpU

Comment: `Me.Filter = "IsActive = '" & Me.IsActive & "'"`
Doing as the video suggests this gives a datatyoe mismatch. How do I store this datatype?

Comment: If IsActive is a yes/no field, the data is -1 and 0 values. Don't use apostrophe delimiters. Apostrophe delimiters are for text type field data. Also, instead of True, use -1 which worked for me.

Comment: @June7 Okay so all is working now so thank you but how do I express all results for the False expression as it doesn't like `"*"`

Comment: As I said, works for me.

Comment: I closed and reopened the form and it worked *facepalm*