# How to Update the Values of a Dropdown in a Subform when the Main Form Changes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two forms:

**InterviewMaster** and **InterviewDetail**

**InterviewDetail** opens up as a subform in **InterviewMaster** and these two forms are linked through a common field called **InterviewID**

In **InterviewDetail** I have a textbox called **Questiontype** as well as combobox called **InterviewDropdown**.

The data in the dropdown varies based on the data on in the textbox. To make this happen, I have a next button to move to the next question. Whenever I click on next the following runs:

```
Dim ctlCombo As Control
 
Set ctlCombo = Forms!InterviewDetail!cmbInterviewDropdown
 
ctlCombo.Requery
```

The Row Source setting for my combobox is set to look up the required answers, again this is based on the value as per the textbox:

```
SELECT [queryAnswerOptions].[Answer] FROM queryAnswerOptions ORDER BY [Answer];
```

So the options are determined by my query called **queryAnswerOptions**

So as I cycle through my questions using my next and previous buttons, the dropdown options are updated based on the value of my textbox. This works perfectly when I open the subform from the navigation pane. However, when I open the main form and click on the next button my  dropdown does not have any values. I've tried requerying the subform with no luck. I've also tried opening the subform in full screen from my main form but this also does not work. I also don't want to go that route as it does not work well with the overall flow of my form.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not necessary to use an object variable to requery combobox. I do not see any filter criteria in the SQL. What is the SQL of queryAnswerOptions? Is the subform in datasheet or continuous view? Cascading combobox is a common topic. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Comment: The SQL for queryAnsweOptions is:

SELECT InterviewAnswers.Answer
FROM InterviewAnswers
WHERE InterviewAnswers.QuestionID = [Forms]![InterviewDetail]![txtQuestionID];

My main form Default View is Single Form
My subform Default View is Split Form

Do you suggest that I change the view types?

I did review the link, not sure I understand the relevance yet but will review it again and see how I can tie it back.

Comment: No, I am not suggesting you change view type. In fact, Datasheet or Continuous would complicate the issue. That's why I provided the link, just to alert you to that. You should edit question to show that SQL. Why use another SQL statement for combobox RowSource? Why not just reference the query name or put that SQL string directly in the combobox RowSource - add the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Is the textbox on subform named QuestionType or txtQuestionID?

Comment: Thank you. Apologies, I misunderstood your initial comment. I did update the RowSource with the SQL statement directly and it worked exactly they way I wanted it.  I am struggling with some of the data in my subform not refreshing as I cycle through the records, but I think that warrants a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the query WHERE criteria parameter is when form is installed as a subform, the form reference no longer works because it must use the subform container control name. I always name container control different from the object it holds, such as ctrDetails.

Option is to put SQL statement directly in combobox RowSource instead of basing combobox RowSource on a dynamic parameterized query object - then it will work whether form is standalone or a subform.

```
SELECT Answer FROM InterviewAnswers WHERE QuestionID = [txtQuestionID] ORDER BY Answer;
```