# MS Access - Data entry form input incorrect field from combobox selection

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a data entry form that has the user select from a couple combo boxes. The choices in the second combo box updates based on the selection from the first. The issue that I am having is, once the form is submitted, the selected details need to write to the source table of the form but as it is currently built the response in combobox1 is inputting the PhaseID instead of the Phase text.

I know that this has something to do with the link between the two comboboxes but every time I try and change the order of the Row Source for each cbo or the bound columns the dependent combobox stops working (blank drop down).

Combobox 1 = PhaseDisputed_1 and is from the table Phases which has 2 columns. PhaseID (Auto Number) and Phase (text string).

Row Source = `SELECT Phases.PhaseID, Phases.Phase FROM Phases`;
Bound Column = 2
Column Count = 2
Column Widths 0”;1”
After Update Event Procedure – questionDisputed_1.Requery

Combobox 2 = QuestionDisputed_1 and options come from the AuditPhaseQuestions table which has 3 columns; QuestionID(Auto Number), PhaseID(from the Phase table), AuditQuestion (Text String).

Row Source = `SELECT Q_PhaseQuestions_ManagerForm.AuditQuestions, Q_PhaseQuestions_ManagerForm.PhaseID FROM Q_PhaseQuestions_ManagerForm;`
Bound Column = 1
Column Count = 2
Column Widths 1”;0”

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here? I really appreciate any help that you can provide!

Comment: You should save PhaseID instead of Phase text. If you aren't going to use ID fields as keys then why include them in RowSource? Why have them in table at all? If ID fields are defined as primary key then use them as such. Cascading combobox is common topic. I do not see any filter criteria for Combobox2 so just how is it dependent on Combobox1? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Comment: Does this answer your question? [connected combo boxes in continuous form - the second combo doesn't show its value if dependent on first combo how could I fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val)

Comment: And https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html has a sample db you can download.

Comment: So you are saying that I should save the key field to my table and then for the reporting that I need to do, use a query that joins the two tables together and pull in the text field at that point?

Comment: *save the key field to my table and then for the reporting that I need to do, use a query that joins the two tables together and pull in the text field at that point* Yes this is the normal case for data stored in your database tables.

Comment: Yes, this is why tables are related by key fields and reason for the designation "relational database". Otherwise, designate the text field as primary key and save it and ignore the ID fields. But saving text values as keys can be less efficient.