# Self-referring query as row source for list box

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I'm trying to make a list box in table view in MS Access, where the list values is dependent on the current record. I does indeed work sometimes, but its very unstable, and sometimes it doesn't work, and then it works again.

The following sql query is the Row Source for the list box:

```
SELECT tbl1.TAG FROM tbl1 WHERE tbl1.[Tag kode] =[KomponentTagkode];
```

The field [KomponentTagKode] is another field in the same table as the list box.

Is there any syntax than can be improved to make this a stable working solution?

I'm aware that this can probably done by using VBA, although I'm not sure which event should pass the change. But I feel that the solution I have already used is more elegant, and I would prefer it if it could be stable.

Comment: What do you mean by 'works sometimes' and 'unstable' - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Comment: When it doesn't work, the drop-down list is empty (it should have 3-4 entries). No error message etc.

Comment: Cascading (conditional/dependent) combobox is a common topic. Need VBA behind form to requery when navigating records.

Comment: Yes, but I'm curious about the possibility of the other solution as it is very neat when it works. I wonder if the functionality is intentional, or just happen to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need to requery the row source of the list box every time the current record changes.

Add the below to the form's code-behind. Just change the control name to that of your list box.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    YourListBoxControlName.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to fully qualify the control in SQL. Open the properties window and paste the row source property exactly as shown in your question - no need to open the SQL editor either. Keep in mind the field name differs in your example, one is `[KomponentTagkode]` and the other `[KomponentID]`. It needs to be the field name as shown in the table, not the form control name.

Comment: Thanks! This solution is not as elegant as I had hoped for, but it works.

Comment: Good to hear. Try to stay away from lists within tables - they will only give you headaches.

Comment: Yeah, I realized my error in the field names, that's why I deleted the comment. Another mistake I did was that my combo as default had set the first column to invisible, while I had only one column in my query, so nothing appeared. 

Thanks also for clarifying that I don't need any separate query for this to work. Excellent! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Probably also want to requery in the AfterUpdate event of KomponentTagkode control or the GotFocus event of the combobox.