# Microsoft Access: How to filter a List Box based on a Combo Box selection?

Tags: database, ms-access

My Access database has a form with a subform. The record in the form and subform is selected from the list box of records. Pretty standard fare so far. The part I can't figure out is that I want the records in the list box to be filtered based on the criteria selected in a combo box in the form. If it's not too much of a stretch from there, I then want it to filter based on multiple criteria from multiple combo box selections (I admit, I may scrap this idea of multiple combo box filters as I'm not necessarily an expert level user and that might be overcomplicating it a bit).

How can I filter the list box in a form based on the selection of a combo box in the same form?

Comment: You describe cascading or dependent combobox/listbox - a common topic https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val. Also, filtering with multiple criteria is common http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Your question is too broad with no attempt to solve issue and no code to analyze.

Comment: Your comment actually answered the question for me, so thank you! Cascading was the term I was missing. I did some searching and was having a hard time finding an answer that worked and various answers weren't quite right (although many were close. It's almost as if there's TOO much info similar to this to find just the right thing). Sometimes it's just knowing what to even ask to be able to find the knowledge. And that link is probably the most helpful instruction I've seen so far. Thank you!