# Displaying a field value in a combo box, but using a subset of the field to populate it

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a ComboBox in Access for assigning records to employees.  Its row source is a query that pulls active employees from the employees table (EmploymentStatus="Active"), so users can only assign records to active employees. When the record (issue) is closed, the AssignedTo field holds the ID of the person who closed it. So far so good. The problem happens when an employee leaves the company and is no longer active. The ComboBox no longer displays their name as you navigate back through the history of records.  Is there a way to always display the name associated with the stored ID in the ComboBox control, but only show a subset of these in the pull down?

I've tried changing the LimitToList property, messing with the column widths, etc., to no avail. I tried setting the "Show Only Row Source" property to no, because didn't want to limit the displayed values to "Show only data values that match the row source". No luck.

The only other solution I can think of is to have two boxes on the form, one for the combo box to choose an active emplyee, and one to store and display the AssignedTo value regardless of employment status.  This seems like a tedious workaround.

Comment: Commonly discussed issue of "conditional/cascading" combobox. Use VBA code to change combobox RowSource depending on if this is existing or new record and when combobox gets focus. Can get complicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [connected combo boxes in continuous form - the second combo doesn't show its value if dependent on first combo how could I fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val)

Comment: Changing the Row Source when the ComboBox GotFocus seems to have worked.  Not as difficult as I feared.