# MS Access handling current value Combo Box not in Row Source anymore

Tags: ms-access

I have a subForm with a Combo Box with Control Source=MemberID and a Row Source Type=Table/Query, the Row Source is a SQL for the table Members.
The current value of the Combo Box is not available anymore in the Row Source and this means that the first row from the Row Source is shown.
Because this is confusing for the user I want to show a message to the user that the current value of MemberID is not available anymore.
How can I do this as simple as possible, I'm not a developer.

Comment: Why is value no longer available? See if this applies to your situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Comment: "*first row from the Row Source is shown*" - exactly what does this mean? Is shown where? Why would user be confused? Why is user viewing a record that does not have data available?

Comment: Members are maintained in a separate system. Every month I import Member data into a MS Access database. In another table of the MS Access database I use a Combo Box with Rowsource the Members table. In this case it happens that the value of the Combo Box no longer exists in the RowSource, the Members table. Hopefully this make more sence?

Comment: So what is record viewed that does not have member info? It has member ID but no member details such as name because member is no longer in the members table download? Perhaps instead of completely replacing dataset, you should append records and not lose any members from the local table? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-microsoft-access. Otherwise, combobox RowSource SQL can be a query that joins tables and have an expression to display "not available" as member name when name is not available: `Nz([name field], "Not Available")`. Anything else means VBA.

Comment: Or workaround described in source referenced in first comment could likely be applied to your situation. Join tables as form RecordSource and in member name textbox, have expression: `=Nz([field name], "Not Available")`.

Comment: Why would members be removed from the external source?

Comment: Why is value no longer available? Why would members be removed from the external source? 
The Member data is managed outside my responsibility. When Members stop their membership, they are no longer included in the CSV file that I receive monthly.

Comment: So what is record viewed that does not have member info?
"first row from the Row Source is shown" - exactly what does this mean? 
As the user clicks on the Combo Box and the current value of the Combo Box is available in the table Members that value is shown in the dropdown list selected. If the current value is not available anymore in the table Members the top row is shown in the dropdown list, unselected.

Comment: The RowSource of the Combo Box is"SELECT MemberID, MemberName FROM Members ORDER BY MemberName;. The BoundColumn is 1. The current value of the Combo Bow is not in the table Members anymore.

Comment: Please explain what to do to get the first row with MemberName="- Not Available".

Comment: I already gave you suggestions on how to have record and/or combobox show a value when name is missing. Exactly what did you not understand?

Comment: Not only the name is missing the record is missing so MemberID and MemberName are missing. My question was how to add a record to a query result so a not available message is shown. I'm not a developer.

Comment: You do not have MemberID saved into your records? Exactly what is this data? If there is no member ID in your local data, then what purpose can a Members table serve? Can use a UNION query to add a "Not Available" line to combobox RowSource. `SELECT 0 AS MemberID, "Not Available" AS MemberName FROM Members UNION MemberID, MemberName FROM Members;`. If you want to ORDER BY MemberName, add a character that will force the "NotAvailable" to sort first: `"_ Not Available"`. I really don't see what benefit this offers.

Comment: I'm sorry but somehow it seems to me that we are talking past each other. A record from the Members table has 2 (and more) fields MemberID and MemberName. But when a member stops being a member then there is no longer a record of that person in the monthly CSV file, which by importing deliberately overwrites the existing local Members table. While the MemberID of this person still appears in my local Function table with the Combo Box. I don't understand your questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257054/discussion-between-june7-and-jan).

Comment: I thanks June7 for his/her time.