Microsoft Access 365 - Combobox with dynamic values
I have a scenario where I'm assigning users and machines to a project.
This is done through a form and subform. The user selects the project and a week commencing date on the main form and can then assign a machine and a user on the subform.
User and Machine are separate comboboxes.
I'd like the list of machines available in the combobox to only include machines which have not already been selected that week.
So creating first record would show the full list available. Second record created would show all except the previously selected value. etc
I have already created records in the subform by just linking the user and machine comboboxes in the normal manner to their underlying source tables. i.e
cboMachines Row Source:
SELECT tblMachines.MachineID, 
       tblMachines.MachineName 
FROM tblMachines;

cboUsers Row Source:
SELECT tblUsers.UserID, 
       tblUsers.UserName 
FROM tblUsers;

These are bound to the underlying table tblWeeklyScheduleDetail
To change this and have cboMachines only include unassigned machines I have tried the following query qrycboMachines set as the Row Source on cboMachines.
SELECT tblMachines.MachineID, 
       tblMachines.MachineName 
FROM tblMachines 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT tblWeeklyScheduleDetail.MachineID 
     FROM tblWeeklyScheduleDetail 
     WHERE tblWeeklyScheduleDetail.MachineID = tblMachines.MachineID 
           AND 
           tblWeeklyScheduleDetail.WeeklyScheduleID = [Forms]![frmWeeklySchedule]![WeeklyScheduleID]
    ); 

Result in Form view is that existing selected values are not displayed but cboMachines does correctly show remaining machines available when clicking on the drop down.
I reverted to SELECT tblMachines.MachineID, tblMachines.MachineName FROM tblMachines; to get the values back and applied qrycboMachines to the On Click event of cmbMachines
Private Sub cboMachines_Click()
    cboMachines.RowSource = qrycboMachines
End Sub

Result is that existing values are displayed but nothing appears in cboMachines After a value is selected.
Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

Try adding "Option Explicit" at the top of the module.

Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Thanks June7. I was able to adapt the answer on that link and now have the solution working as expected.
