Dependent Dropdowns
I have looked for this but haven't been able to get anything to work.
I am trying to use the dropdown "Facility Name" as the criteria to run a query "QBF_Query". Then "Department" should return the results from QBF_Query.
QBF Query:
Field: Facility
Table: Department Names
Criteria: [Forms]![BCP Document Dashboard]![Facility Name]

Field: Department Name
Table: Department Names

BCP Tracker Form:
Dropdown: Facility Name
Control Source: Table Facility Name
On-change: Run QBF_Macro

Dropdown: Department
Control Source: [QBF_Query]![Department Name]

QBF_Macro
Query Name: QBF_Query
View: Datasheet
Data Mode: Edit

Facility Name Table:
Field: Facility Name (short text)

Department Name Table;
Field: ID
Type: AutoNumber

Field: Facility Name
Type: Short Text
Control: [Facility Name].[Facility Name]

Field: Department Name
Type: Short Text

I tried the above steps and wanted to have the form dropdowns return the results of QBF_Query but it is still returning all results rather than just the results with criteria from Facility Name dropdown.

You describe "cascading" or "dependent" combobox (or listbox) which is a common topic.  Need to Requery combobox, not view query. Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Does this answer your question? Cascading combo boxes

While what you are saying makes sense, I am not picking up what to do with it. The links you provided talk about it, but I am unsure of how to do requeries or anything of that nature. I tried adding a screenshot but that didn't work unfortunately.

Use VBA instead of macros.
