Wrong column/value being displayed in a combo box when getting results from a query
I have a form that has a multivalue field in it, being shown through a combo box. When I pull the data from a table I can get it to display a persons name but store their ID number in the table, making it more user friendly. When I reopened the form the names would appear in the field instead of the numbers, keeping them hidden. As shown
Being made from a table

How its displayed

However when I pull the same information from a query, even though it has the relevant data it still loads in the ID numbers but when pressing the drop down will show the names as normal.
Being made from a query

How its displayed

Just to show the query is still getting the correct data

I make the combo box the same way and have tried it with other queries in the past that have worked but for some reason the screen acts like there is an issue with the data as shown
I have tried recreating the combo box, linking it with the relevant field it will save to but when I use this particular query it still loads the data back in to the field incorrectly. Could this be to do with the fact that the people who are not free are that time are excluded by the query and this would mean it cannot find their name to display so leave it as ID numbers ?
If so I would need to look at a way of returning all results but not displaying them

The second setup doesn't show the "Hide key column" option. By "query" do you mean an SQL statement in RowSource property? I never use the build wizards because they do things I don't like. I also never use multi-value field. Your conclusion about not showing names when combobox is "conditional" is correct. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val. This is a design not coding issue and therefore question is not appropriate for SO.

I go to query design and instantly switch to SQL to create my queries rather than the wizards for the same reason. I agree multivalued fields are not great but unfortunately limited to using them. I will try using the focus strategy described in the link provided

To solve this I had it change the rowsource to a new statement that pulled the restricted data OnGotFocus, then OnLostFocus I returned it to the table so it had all the data and displayed the names as it was trying to do.
Cannot post the sql code as this is a live assessment but similar to below;
Private Sub Trainers_GotFocus()
  Me.Trainers.RowSource = "ONLY WANTED RESULTS"
End Sub
Private Sub Trainers_LostFocus()
 Me.Trainers.RowSource = "EVERY RESULT"
End Sub


Note that after setting .RowSource you shouldn't need to call .Requery, this happens automatically. (Perhaps multivalued fields behave differently)

Correct, just tested that, thanks
