MS Access Combo filter as type in a multiline form
I have code that works to filter the combo options as desired but it clears the combo boxes from previous line items.
I found this code that has the affect I want but I'm not familiar enough with this language to know where to edit it so it will only affect the current line items combo box.
Here is the code I'm using
Private Sub cboProductID_Change()
    FilterComboAsYouType Me.cboProductID, "SELECT * FROM Products", "ProductName"
End Sub

Public Sub FilterComboAsYouType(combo As ComboBox, defaultSQL As String, lookupField As String)
Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(combo.Text) > 0 Then
        strSQL = defaultSQL & " WHERE " & lookupField & " LIKE '*" & combo.Text & "*'"
    Else
        strSQL = defaultSQL    'This is the default row source of combo box
    End If
    combo.RowSource = strSQL
    combo.Dropdown
End Sub


Your question is somehow vague to me, but it seems you do not want to filter the combo (which this code does), but to select the first match as you type. Is this correct?

See if this applies to your situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

The code is doing what I want it to. I want matches to the typed value. If I type Solder I want all options that have that term in them.
