In Microsoft Access how do I populate a combobox from a query that is calculated at the time of the arrow press to cascade the combobox?
I am making a database with a cascading form. The form has 2 relational combo boxes. I can populate the first one easily, however the second combobox is dependent on whatever was selected on each row.
Basically I select an item category and then an item code depending on what category I am under.

I have set up a query that works on a tempvar. I use the following code to get the tempvar:
TempVars("itemcat") = Me.cat_comb.Column(1)

DoCmd.Requery

This works great if i set it to run on AfterUpdate on the category combobox. The problem with this is that the next row will not update the list of allowable item codes, unless a category is clicked. This creates a weird scenario for the end user.
My idea was to run the code on BeforeUpdate of the item code combobox, however this seems to not work. Is there any way for me to achieve the result that I need?

Also run code in Current event. What is the 'weird' scenario? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

Are  you using a continues form (multiple items form), or is this just 6 combo boxes placed on a form?
