How to Refresh all in Microsoft Access / VBA
I have a form with 3 cascading combo boxes that allow the user to select a given work site, equipment pakage, and specific equipment item.
I've done this with three queries, using the method from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFOACVzMjiQ
However, I need to be able to output the equipment details such as width, length, motor power to text boxes so the user can copy that information into other documents.
The cascading combo boxes are working, however the text fields do not update upon a new equipment selection until I press the "Refresh All" button in the Ribbon.
I have tried using Me.Refresh and Me.textField.Requery, triggered by "after update" on the last combo box, but this doesn't work, or triggers a Compile error "invalid qualifier"
Here's all the code I currently have:
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cbProjectCode_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cbPackageNo.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cbPackageNo_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cbEquipmentNo.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cbEquipmentNo_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Refresh
End Sub


How are you populating textboxes? Are you saving this to a table? Include equipment details in combobox RowSource and expressions in textboxes reference those combobox columns: =cbEquipmentNo.Column(1).

I'm pulling data from a table that has all the info - I've got three queries that update as the combobox selections are made - so that the final query outputs a single record with all the info I want to display.
The text fields pull data from the form - and they work, although I cannot get them to update their content until I click the "Refresh All" button on the Ribbon.
I don't want to have all the fields of the query be visible in the combo box, I just want a single field to appear, and the rest should appear in the text boxes below.

Okay, you are using cascading comboboxes. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483138/connected-combo-boxes-in-continuous-form-the-second-combo-doesnt-show-its-val

BTW, fields need not be visible in combobox for expression to reference them. Set ColumnWidth for those columns to 0. However, this won't help with your cascading combobox issue.

I am not having an issue with the cascading combo boxes.

I want information from my table - as filtered / queried via the combo boxes, to be displayed in text boxes. I've implemented your first suggestion and they now update according to the equipment selected which is great!
However, I can no-longer unlock a text box if I want to allow editing to that field, as they are now bound to the combo box expression.
When the text fields pull from the final query, they are editable (when unlocked), but the issue is that the fields do not update their content until I click "Refresh All". I want to know if I can trigger "Refresh all" with VBA.

So these comboboxes are not BOUND? I am still rather lost on what exactly you are doing. However, perhaps you should investigate this: CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DataRefreshAll".

No code is needed.
Create the three textboxes and bind them using these ControlSources respectively:
=[cbProjectCode]

=[cbPackageNo]

=[cbEquipmentNo]

These will, at any time, reflect the current values of the comboboxes.
If you need the value from another column than the bound, specify which column to retrieve:
=[cbPackageNo].[Column](1)

Note, that Column(0) is the first column.
